# Reduce space after \includegraphics

Tags: spacing, floats

I do not know how to reduce the vertical space between a figure and the following text or line.

LaTeX code:

```
\begin{document} 
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 5.0cm]{logo.png}
\HRule
\end{document}
```

where `\HRule` is defined as `\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}}`

I want to reduce the space between the figure and the line. I have tried with `\vspace`, but it did not work.

I hope you have a solution.

Answer (score 11):

In this elementary instance, you can use the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%
% The [demo] option is just for this example
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 5.0cm]{logo.png}\par
\kern\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip+2mm\relax
\HRule
\end{document}​
```

Here `\kern` inserts vertical space. Since the `\Hrule` is set on the baseline and in a new paragraph, the vertical distance is reduced by `\baselineskip+\parskip`. An additional `2mm` pushes `\Hrule` down far enough to leave a `1mm` gap between the image and the line.

So, for example, if you want a `10bp` gap between the image and your `\Hrule`, you would use

```
\kern\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip+1mm+10bp\relax
```

---

In general, if you contain your images inside a `figure` environment, you can modify the length `\intextsep`. For this, read the [`layouts` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf).

Comment: @HenrikU: Consider [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764) so it can be "closed".

Comment: Wouldn't `\par\kern10pt\hrule height 2mm` be easier? :)